# Stationary distribution of positive symmetric stochastic matrix with Perron Frobenius

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

Let P be a symmetric matrix with all positive entries and all rows (and therefore columns) summing to one. It is easy to check that $\pi=(1,...1)$ is an eigenvector of eigenvalue $1$. By the Perron Frobenius theorem, one can conclude that this is in fact the only eigenvector of size $1$. I am wondering whether in the symmetric stochastic case there is an easier way to see this claim. My motivation is to give a simple proof that a reversible irreducible markov chain has the uniform distribution as its unique stationary distribution.

Comment: a standard approach to show the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda_1$ is 1, is to show that any $\mathbf v$ satisfying $P\mathbf v= \mathbf v$ cannot have a maximum component $\gt$ the minimum component because multiplication by $P$ gives a (non-trivial) convex combination of each component.  You get algebraic multiplicity $=1$ for free by spectral theorem.

Comment: I see. Can you also show that $-1$ is not an eigenvalue?

Comment: re-run my above argument on $P^2$

Comment: Very nice. If you write this as an answer I will accept. If not I will do it eventually for posterity.